# Grid for MVC3 razor - paging from procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Grid is working correct. Unfortunately if I click page 2 I don`t know how to send this information to controller (JSON? - and rebuild grid with data from procedure) ? Because I would like to prepare paging using procedure.

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
    grid.Bind(Model.DodajTematProceduraZwyklyUzytkownik, rowCount: Convert.ToInt32(Model.DodajTematProceduraZwyklyUzytkownik[0].zmienna), autoSortAndPage: false);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
    @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id="grid" },
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Temat")
        ));
}
```

This I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use JTable.org project to fix this problem.